# Dollar ($) sign at beginning of string

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm currently working on an asynchronous TCP-Client. I am able to send and receive messages. However, the following code is driving me crazy at the moment:

```
int rx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
char[] rcvd = new char[rx + 1];
System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetDecoder();
int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, rx, rcvd, 0);
System.String szData = new System.String(rcvd);
```

Normally, everything works fine - but as soon as a message starts with a dollar sign ($), I only see this char.

I was searching for a long time but I couldn't find any solution....

Comment: When the message starts with a dollar sign, what is the value of rx?

Comment: Just a quick thought are you sure the text is encoded in ASCII and not UTF7/8/16 ??

Comment: funnily, int rx has the value of '1' instead of 15...

Comment: @Robert: it's ASCII for sure, I have tried other encodings as well

Comment: More information regarding your socket please. Net sockets? Protocol?

Comment: @ChrisBD it's a net socket, protocol is tcp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Receive` can complete when any data is received at the socket - not necessarily a whole "message". You have to buffer the received data until a whole message ( as defined in your protocol ) has been received.

Comment: you're right. in my case, messages are devided by line feeds. What would be the best way to seperate these messages when using async callbacks?

Comment: You need a buffer to store partial messages as they arrive. When you detect a whole message in the buffer, pass it on to be processed. As you are doing this asynchronously, you have to make sure each partial message is added in the order it is received.